# iOS Simulator crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on removeFromParent (Xcode Beta5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode5, ios-simulator, sprite-kit

Running Xcode beta 5, I get following issue when running a freshly created project (Game Template) by just changing touchesBegan() in GameScene.swift

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for i in 0...100 {
        var trail = SKSpriteNode()
        trail.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)
        trail.name = "trail"
        self.addChild(trail)
    }

    //delete old trails
    self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("trail") {
        node, stop in
        node.runAction(SKAction.removeFromParent())
    }
}
```

Only thing that gets done is adding some childNodes with a name set and then trying to remove them with the SKAction.removeFromParent. This crashes in Simulator with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Same code works when using in a Playground

```
import SpriteKit

var node = SKNode()

for i in 0...100 {
    var trail = SKSpriteNode()
    trail.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0)
    trail.name = "trail"
    node.addChild(trail)
}

//delete old trails
node.enumerateChildNodesWithName("trail") {
    node, stop in
    node.runAction(SKAction.removeFromParent())
}
```

After crash of simulator, xcode hangs stacktrace on
SKCRenderer::preprocessSpriteImp()

This used to work in XCode beta 3.

Comment: I heard that some xcode6/swift sprite features only work in iOS 8

Comment: Target was iOS8 and I guess Simulator is running accordingly. Anyway, I updated my original post to include an additional information, as this used to work in beta3.

Comment: Tested recently with Xcode6 beta6, still applies ...